# Changing argument inside a function using yield

Tags: ruby

I am new to the concept of yield and currently practising it.
I was expecting to get `["bread", "JUICY", "bread"]`
but I got `["bread", "steak", "bread"]`.

Can you please help me understand why? And how can I fix my code?

```
def burger(patty)
  if block_given?
    yield(patty)
  end
  return ["bread", patty, "bread"]
end


# TODO: Change 'steak'to 'JUICY'using yield
juicy_burger = burger("steak") do |patty|
  patty = "JUICY"
end
p juicy_burger
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> juicy_burger = burger("steak") do |patty|
>   patty = "JUICY"
> end
> ```

Reassignments like this are not propagated to the outer scopes. Once this block returns, `patty` "reverts" to its initial value.

Solution? Use the overwritten value while it's still in scope.

```
def burger(patty)
  if block_given?
    patty = yield(patty)
    # ^ shadow the parameter here. 
    # doesn't have to be a shadow. You can use any name. new_patty = yield(patty)
  end
  return ["bread", patty, "bread"]
end


juicy_burger = burger("steak") do |patty|
  "JUICY #{patty}" # <- simple return here
end
p juicy_burger # >> ["bread", "JUICY steak", "bread"]
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Just to add that the block argument `|patty|` isn't used or needed and could be omitted from the method call and the yield.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: it's used in my version, but you're right.

Answer (score 1):

The variable is local to the function and you did not save back the value yield returned. The code below will give you `["bread", "JUICY", "bread"]`

```
def burger(patty)
  if block_given?
    patty = yield(patty) # <-- this is the diff
  end
  return ["bread", patty, "bread"]
end


# TODO: Change 'steak'to 'JUICY'using yield
juicy_burger = burger("steak") do |patty|
  patty = "JUICY"
end
p juicy_burger
```

Comment: and like sergio mentioned there no need to assign inside the block since it's local